# How can i get product visibility in WooCommerce loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, product

How can i get the value of a product visibility ?

I would like to set a conditional display in a loop, based on product visibility if hidden.

Something like :

```
if($my_product is hidden) { 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the [`WC_Product` method `is_visible()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.7.1/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L1498-L1506) on the `WC_Product` Object like:

```
global $product;

// Be sure to get the WC_Product instance object
if( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
}

// Check product visibility
if( ! $product->is_visible() ) {
    // Not visible
} else {
    // Visible
}
```

It should work.